# Module not find require - chaning image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to create a flexible component, which will change image if I drag the mouse over him.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class GitLogo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <img src={require('../resources/GitHub-Mark-Light-32px.png')}
                 onMouseOver={e => (e.currentTarget.src = require('../resources/GitHub-Mark-32px.png'))}
                 onMouseOut={e => (e.currentTarget.src = require('../resources/GitHub-Mark-Light-32px.png'))}
            alt="Logo"/>
        );
    }
}
```

And here everything is working just fine. Right now I would like to make my component more flexible, and allow him to read images paths via props.

```js
<GitLogo beforehover="../resources/GitHub-Mark-Light-32px.png" afterhover="../resources/GitHub-Mark-32px.png"/>
```

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class GitLogo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <img src={require('../resources/GitHub-Mark-Light-32px.png')}
                     onMouseOver={e => (e.currentTarget.src = require( this.props.afterhover ))}
                 onMouseOut={e => (e.currentTarget.src = require('../resources/GitHub-Mark-Light-32px.png'))}
            alt="Logo"/>
        );
    }
}
```

But am keep on getting errors: Cannot find module '../resources/GitHub-Mark-32px.png'
What is the best solution? Is require() good function, or I should use smth else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image needs to be loaded first so you need to require them while passing the as props. Change your props passing code to the following...

```
<GitLogo beforehover={require("../resources/GitHub-Mark-Light-32px.png")} afterhover={require("../resources/GitHub-Mark-32px.png")}/>
```

And use the props in the component just like that...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class GitLogo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <img src={require('../resources/GitHub-Mark-Light-32px.png')}
                     onMouseOver={e => (e.currentTarget.src = this.props.afterhover)}
                 onMouseOut={e => (e.currentTarget.src = require('../resources/GitHub-Mark-Light-32px.png'))}
            alt="Logo"/>
        );
    }
}
```